# Sharepoint 2013: can a page automatically filter content based on credentials?

Tags: 2013, filter, login, data

Is there a way for Sharepoint 2013 to display only certain data on a page based on the credentials of the person logged in?  To clarify:  My project Director wants to visit a page and automatically see only his projects.  He also wants to be able to edit only his projects.  Conversely, no one else should be able to edit his projects.

Is this doable outside the obvious permissions settings?? PLEASE NOTE:  I am not talking about permissions here, the same list needs to be viewable by all - just various rows on the list to some and not others. Same with editing.  If there is a permissions feature that will select certain rows in a list please illuminate me.

Comment: Yes, this is a basic feature of permissions in SharePoint.

Comment: No, that is not what I'm asking about but thank you.  Unless you can set permissions on one list to only reveal certain line items that isn't a solution for this issue.

Comment: Yes you can set permissions per line in a list, and only those with permission to that item will see it.